# Why Inserting records in MS access using C# takes alot of time C#?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

My data is composed of 33133 rows and about 45 columns. I am inserting data from datagridview into MS Access database(accdb). I am using local database file.

I tried inserting 33133 rows for just 13 columns and it took literally 15-20 minutes to get into database. I am using high end PC. I can't imagine how much time it will take for 45 columns. I searched around and read various answers regarding bulkcopy using DAO but it doesn't serve my purpose and to be honest the solutions were out of my understanding.

Why its taking so long? Am i doing something wrong? If yes, please guide me.

here is my simple code(I am using query from table adapter):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            this.architecture_TowerBTableAdapter.InsertQueryTest(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value),
              Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value),
              Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value),
              Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value),
              Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value));

        }
```

**EDIT**
In comments, John suggested to try Datatable binding. The datagridview populates with data but database is still empty. Here is my code.

```
        string PathConn = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = '" + tb_TableBPath.Text + "' ; Extended Properties = \"Excel 8.0; HDR = YES;\";";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + tb_SheetB.Text + "$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        this.architectureTowerBBindingSource.DataSource = dt;
        this.architectureTowerBBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.architecture_TowerBTableAdapter.Update(this.pCLiveDB_AykonDataSet.Architecture_TowerB);
```

Comment: Access is not widely known for its performance.  What database driver are you using?

Comment: You should not be looping through the rows of the grid and inserting each one individually. You have a typed `DataSet`. Create an instance of the appropriate `DataTable` and bind it to the grid, preferably via a `BindingSource`. Any data added to the grid will be added to the `DataTable` automatically. If you're adding data in code, add it to the `DataTable`. You can then save the data as a single batch with a call to `Update` on the table adapter.

Comment: @john I tried your solution but somehow the database isn't getting updated. It doesn't throw any error though.

Comment: @john I added my code in the question. I am trying to find solution but hitting the wall.

Comment: If you expect to save data from  this.pCLiveDB_AykonDataSet.Architecture_TowerB then that's where you need to put the data in the first place, not some other DataTable you just created. Also, set AcceptChangesDuringFill to False on your data adapter. That way, every row is marked Added and is ready for insertion. Otherwise, they will be marked Unchanged and will be ignored when you call Update.

Comment: @john I am importing data from excel into datagridview and then from datagridview to database. Thats why I am using that Datatable. I am trying for your solution coz it seems easiest and quickest.

Comment: I understand that, but my solution is to import the data into a `DataTable` (which can then be displayed in a `DataGridView` if desired, but that is irrelevant) and then saved to the database from that same `DataTable`. There's no point importing into one `DataTable` and then trying to save from another that doesn't contain any data. The `RowState` of each `DataRow` also has to be `Added` if you want it to be inserted when you call `Update`. I've told you exactly what you need to do. Now you just need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is OFTEN that the conneciton is not held open.
You also don't mention if a network of some type is involved (or is this local file??).

But, batch out the row adding to a data table.

You can use say this code approach:

(send out say 1000 rows each time.

```
                // we have a table called rstFrom - 20,000 rows for this test

        const int BatchSize = 1000;
        int RowCount = 0;


                strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblBigTo WHERE ID = 0";
                cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL;

                DataTable rstToTable = new DataTable();
                rstToTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());  // load table structure (no reocrds

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                OleDbCommandBuilder daU = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);

                // proces all from rows

                Debug.Print("start trans");
                DateTime T = DateTime.Now;

                foreach (DataRow FromRow in rstFrom.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow MyNewRow = rstToTable.NewRow();

                    MyNewRow["FirstName"] = FromRow["FirstName"];
                    MyNewRow["LastName"] = FromRow["LastName"];
                    MyNewRow["City"] = FromRow["City"];
                    // etc. more columns

                    rstToTable.Rows.Add(MyNewRow);
                    RowCount += 1;
                    
                    if (RowCount >= BatchSize)
                    {
                        da.Update(rstToTable);
                        rstToTable.Rows.Clear();
                        RowCount = 0;
                        Debug.Write("out " + BatchSize.ToString() +  Convert.ToString((char)10));
                    }

                }

                // write out any rows left in buffer
                if (rstToTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    da.Update(rstToTable);
                    rstToTable.Rows.Clear();
                    RowCount = 0;
                }

                Debug.Print((DateTime.Now - T).Seconds.ToString());
```

So,, what we do in above, is create a data table. We pull zero rows from target (to get table schema).

We then just loop each "from row". In my example, my from rows are from a source table, but that would be the grid in your case.

If no network is involved, this should not take more then say about 1 minute to run.